# twilio-ruby stops working after upgrading to ruby 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio, twilio-api, ruby-3.1

I have been using the twilio api for 3 years to send messages and it worked perfectly. After upgrading from ruby 2.6 to ruby 3.1.3, Twilio is no longer working. We are using twilio-ruby 5.74.2. We are getting the error `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):`. I have the following code:

```
def send_pin_through_twilio
        client = Twilio::REST::Client.new
        client.messages.create({
            from: ENV["twilio_phone_number"],
            to: self.phone_number,
            body: "Hello from ...! Your one-time pin is #{self.one_time_pin}."
        })
end
```

We get the following error:

```
2023-02-03T17:11:25.312087+00:00 app[web.2]: F, [2023-02-03T17:11:25.311995 #4] FATAL -- : [0d0b1732-1dbc-4170-a3d3-ba99bb7a676e]
2023-02-03T17:11:25.312089+00:00 app[web.2]: [0d0b1732-1dbc-4170-a3d3-ba99bb7a676e] ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)):
2023-02-03T17:11:25.312089+00:00 app[web.2]: [0d0b1732-1dbc-4170-a3d3-ba99bb7a676e]
2023-02-03T17:11:25.312090+00:00 app[web.2]: [0d0b1732-1dbc-4170-a3d3-ba99bb7a676e] app/models/user.rb:157:in `send_pin_through_twilio'
2023-02-03T17:11:25.312090+00:00 app[web.2]: [0d0b1732-1dbc-4170-a3d3-ba99bb7a676e] app/controllers/api/v3/users_controller.rb:127:in `login_next'
2023-02-03T17:11:25.320370+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=PUT path="/api/v3/users/login_next" host=app.hiwave.co request_id=0d0b1732-1dbc-4170-a3d3-ba99bb7a676e fwd="73.179.143.247,108.162.212.48" dyno=web.2 connect=0ms service=2790ms status=500 bytes=307 protocol=https
```

Here is our initializer for reference:

```
Twilio.configure do |config|
  config.account_sid = ENV["accountsid"]
  config.auth_token = ENV["authtoken"]
end
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Change this:

```rb
client.messages.create({
  from: ENV["twilio_phone_number"],
  to: self.phone_number,
  body: "Hello from ...! Your one-time pin is #{self.one_time_pin}."
})
```

To this:

```rb
client.messages.create(
  from: ENV["twilio_phone_number"],
  to: self.phone_number,
  body: "Hello from ...! Your one-time pin is #{self.one_time_pin}."
)
```

Note that the second example is not a hash, it is using keyword arguments.

This is caused by [the separation of positional and keyword arguments in Ruby 3](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/).

If you had updated to Ruby 2.7 then you would have received a warning about this rather than an error. By skipping from 2.6 to 3 you missed the warning and went straight to an error.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that's because you're using a hash as parameter while the method is now waiting for keyword arguments, try to replace the method call with this line:

```rb
client.messages.create(from: ENV["twilio_phone_number"], to: self.phone_number, body: "Hello from ...! Your one-time pin is #{self.one_time_pin}.")
```